# How to install src package in SUSE?

Tags: opensuse, suse, zypper

I use `zypper si` command to install source package in SUSE:

```
localhost:/dev/disk/by-id # zypper si zlib
Reading installed packages...
Loading repository data...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following source package is going to be installed:
  zlib

1 source package to install.
Overall download size: 587.0 KiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 597.7 KiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/? shows all options] (y): y
Checking for file conflicts: ........................................................................................................[done]
```

But when I use the command: `zypper se` to check package state, it shows "not installed":

```
localhost:/dev/disk/by-id # zypper se zlib
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name | Summary                  | Type
--+------+--------------------------+-----------
  | zlib | Data Compression Library | srcpackage
```

Could anyone give some clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the source package has been installed successfully in `/usr/src/package` folder. But it is not marked as "`installed`" state from this [document](https://www.suse.com/documentation/opensuse103/opensuse103_reference/data/sec_rpm_quellen.html):

> HINT: Source packages can be copied from the installation medium to the hard disk and unpacked with YaST. They are not, however, marked as installed ([i]) in the package manager. This is because the source packages are not entered in the RPM database. Only installed operating system software is listed in the RPM database. When you install a source package, only the source code is added to the system.

Comment: Well then, how to install the binaries you get from the source?

Comment: That, my friend, is a whole other can o' worms...

Answer (score 0):

The package is not yet installed, you need the `rpmbuild` command to create it first. Zypper only downloaded the sources needed for compilation.

`cd` into `/usr/src/packages` and do as `root` or `sudo rpmbuild -ba SPEC/yourfilename.spec` and it will be compiled into the directory with your processor architecture name. For me would that be `/usr/src/packages/RPMS/x86_64/`.

Install it with

```
rpm -ivh /path/to/yourfilename.rpm
```